# TweetSharp not allowing a search - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, search, tweetsharp

I am having problems running the following code.  Authentication works fine but it fails on the search every time.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
Console.WriteLine("Bot started: " + DateTime.Now);
            service  = new TwitterService(customerKey, customerKeySecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

            TwitterSearchResult tweets = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#FF", Count = 100 });

            if (tweets != null)
            {

                foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
            }

            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

The error looks like this:

*Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I've tried adding the using directive System.Security.Permissions, although it isn't used.  Still no luck.

Comment: I assume this is a runtime error you're seeing. What version of System.Security.Permissions do you have in your project? If you open your csproj file in a text editor (or unload and edit in VS) and look at the hint path for the reference, is the assembly actually at the specified location? If yes and yes, perhaps you need a binding redirect in your web/app.config file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions for instructions.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is a runtime error.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is a runtime error. The entire contents of the csproj are listed below.  I can tweet, but anything beyond this - search, ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline etc give me the same error.  My bot is set to read and write.

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

`  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="TweetSharp" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project> `

Comment: Ah, I don't have any projects using PackageReference (I'm still using packages.config). Sorry I can't be of more help.